# Путь к файлу в JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Есть selectbox инклюдит php файлы по выбору. Файлы находятся для инклюда в этой же директории category1.php, category2.php, category3.php, category4.php. Если эти файлы переместить в поддиректорию к примеру includes/category1.php то каким образом в скрипте прописать путь к файлам?

```html
 <div class="select">
<form>
<select id="projects">
<option value='category1'>Category - 1</option>
<option value='category2'>Category - 2</option>
<option value='category3'>Category - 3</option>
<option value='category4'>Category - 4</option>
</select>
</form>
<script>
$('select').on('change', function() {
  fileGet($(this).val());
});

function fileGet(file) {
  file = file + ".php";
  console.log(file);
  $.ajax({
    url: file,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $("#container").html(html);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Так `file = "includes/" + file + ".php";` или так `file = "/includes/" + file + ".php";`

Comment: Спасибо заработало!